# How can I get my add-ons menus available in newly created Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the workflow of a Google Sheet add-on. I'm using it in a sheet in which the script is bound too and it works perfectly fine. However, when I create a new Spreadsheet I can see my add-on menu created under `Add-ons` but not its submenus. Also, if I look at the executions I get:
`Exception: You do not have permission to perform that action.` when trying to execute `Spreadsheet.getUi()` to create the menus.

I have deployed a new version and adjusted the settings in the Marketplace SDK to match with those of the deployment. Also, I have all the scopes of the script matching in the OAuth consent screen in my google project and in the Marketplace SDK.

The only way it works is if I go into `Add-ons > Manage add-ons` And click on `Use in this document`

What is the correct workflow here to have my add-on menus available automatically in newly created Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onOpen (e)` is a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), and it is under a series of [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions), specially

> They cannot access services that require authorization.

Before you click *"Use in this document"*, the add-on is in [installed mode](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#installed_versus_enabled) and the event object `e.authMode` has value `AuthMode.NONE`, so your trigger can't access the `Properties` service. Only after you click *"Use in this document"* the trigger goes into "enabled mode" (`e.authMode === AuthMode.LIMITED`), and you can access `Properties`.

To fix that, you need to test if the add-on is installed or enabled, and show a menu option that allows the user to enable it if it is only installed. See the example below:

```
function onOpen (e) {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu(); // Or DocumentApp.
  if (e && e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE) {
    // Add a normal menu item (works in all authorization modes).
    menu.addItem('Enable add-on', 'enableAddOn');
  } else {
    // Add a menu item based on properties (doesn't work in AuthMode.NONE).
    var properties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
    var workflowStarted = properties.getProperty('workflowStarted');
    if (workflowStarted) {
      menu.addItem('Check workflow status', 'checkWorkflow');
    } else {
      menu.addItem('Start workflow', 'startWorkflow');
    }
  }
  menu.addToUi();
}

function enableAddOn () {
  onOpen();
}
```

When it is only installed, user sees only the option "Enable add-on". By clicking on it, the add-on becomes enabled, so the function can simply call `onOpen()` and the `if..else` will load the correct menu options.

Notice that you only need this fix because your simple trigger `onOpen (e)` is using the **Properties** service. If you remove that, there is no need to test the installed/enabled mode.

Comment: great first contribution.  Everything makes more sense now. But I still wonder, functions that create installable triggers usually need to be run manually. Can I force run these functions to install an `onChange()` trigger, for example, from the `enableAddOn` function or maybe the `onOpen()` itself?

Comment: Yes, you can because the `enableAddOn` function will be in `AuthMode.FULL` mode. Just be cautious with the restriction "_Installable triggers always run under the account of the person who created them._" on the installable triggers.